# Add custom color glowing effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to add custom color glowing effect.
I already did:

`/team modify Owner color dark_red`

but it still doesn't work, I still get the white color, even if I'm on the team.

[image: Not working color glow]

Comment: This works for me in 1.16.3. Which version were you playing in and which exact commands did you use?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't exactly pinpoint what version of Minecraft you're playing on (from the textures, it seems like 1.14+), it does at least look like you are the owner of a multiplayer server. Here are a few troubleshooting options you might have available to you:

- **Try recreating the team again** - At least through some of my testing, it seems like what you are trying to do works perfectly fine in vanilla 1.14. You could try recreating the team again by following these steps:

  ```
    1. /team remove Owner (optional, if you want to remove the old team)
    2. /team add Owner "Owner"
    3. /team modify Owner color dark_red
    4. /team join Owner [your username]
  ```
- **Reapply the glowing effect** - There might be an issue with the glowing effect being applied *before* you changed the team color / added yourself to the team, so try reapplying the glowing effect. If you're using some sort of plugin that gives you the glowing effect, it might not be able to change color based on team color.
- **Try using a custom glow plugin** - If vanilla teams aren't working for you, or if you prefer an easier-to-use way to get a custom glow, then a plugin might help. I found two plugins, one for 1.9-1.12, and the other for 1.14 (appears to also work for 1.15) which both seem to do what you want (apply a custom glowing color to yourself/an entity) via a simple command or a GUI, which should be easier to use than vanilla teams. I've linked both below:

***Glower*** / GUI-Based *(1.9 - 1.12)* - https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/glower-1-9-1-12-custom-player-glows.50958/

***SimpleGlow*** / Chat Command-based *(1.14 - 1.15)* - https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/simpleglow.51810/

Hope this helped!